# I get the following error in r when using mgcv package no applicable method for 'smooth.construct' applied

Tags: r, statistics, gam, mgcv

I am trying to use a gam function (mgcv package) to decompose the response variable pulse voltage into a combination of polynomial and exponential components. I get the following error:
Error in UseMethod("smooth.construct") :
no applicable method for 'smooth.construct' applied to an object of class "ex.smooth.spec"
The model code is below:
model = gam(pulse_data$pulse_volt ~ s(pulse_data$pulse_current, bs = "ex") + s(pulse_data$pulse_current, bs = "cr", k = 10), data = pulse_data,method = 'REML')

Now there are two things I would like to know.
One is I am trying to decompose pulse_volt into voltage response from circuits subcomponents so I have modeled one as polynomial response and the other is exponential response(both not measured). There is only one input and 2 output. Can we use GAM to do this assuming no interaction between sub components?
The other question is related to model syntax basically I think we need two sets of smooth factors one is for polynomial term and the other is for exponential term. So will this model reflect my hypothesis?

Note:the data is clean and scaled.

Comment: Remove `pulse_data$` from the model formula.

Comment: And I don't think GAM smoothers are what you actually want for your decomposition.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much for your comment. I was also thinking of the same thing. I am planning to use custom objective function using splines with global optimisation. Please tell me if my approach would be good. Also please suggest me if you have any better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `"ex"` basis in mgcv, hence the error. I'm not sure where you got the impression that this was a valid basis, but it is not.